# Complex analysis describing set of points?

Tags: complex-analysis

Describe the set of points in the plan z for which  $\arg\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}=α$ where $α$ is a real number.
I know I should multiply up and down with $\bar z+ 1$ but then what?

Note that $\bar z = x - iy$

Comment: Hint: $\text{arg}(z\pm 1)$ is the angle between the line joining $z$ and $\pm 1$ and the real axis. This means $\text{arg}\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)$ is the angle between two lines crossing at $z$. If you construct a circle containing $z$ and $\pm 1$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me to assume $\alpha=\pi/4$ for the simplicity and let me consider a more general case as follows:  $$\text{arg}\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)=\pi/4$$ So we have $$\text{arg}(z-z_1)-\text{arg}(z-z_2)=\text{arg}\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)=\pi/4$$ If we set $\phi=\text{arg}(z-z_1),~~\theta=\text{arg}(z-z_2)$ then $\phi-\theta=\pi/4$ and so $$\tan(\phi-\theta)=1$$ In fact, we have $$1=\frac{\tan\phi-\tan\theta}{1+\tan\phi\tan\theta}=\frac{\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}-\frac{y-y_2}{x-x_2}}{1+\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}\frac{y-y_2}{x-x_2}}$$ Now take $x_1=1, x_2=-1,~~ y_1=0=y_2$ and so: $$\frac{\frac{y}{x-1}-\frac{y}{x+1}}{1+\frac{y}{x-1}\frac{y}{x+1}}=1\longrightarrow \frac{2y}{x^2-1+y^2}=1$$ Which geometric flat shape does the latter equation illustrate?

Comment: In my book the answer is Circle with center (0;1/tgα) and radius 1/sinα ...but I dont know how to transform that here..

Comment: @amWhy, what???